# Justification of a floor function simplification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider the expression: 
$\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rfloor$, Where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (natural numbers)

How would I show that $\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ is the same thing as $\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor$ .

Comment: What is $\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor$ when $k=1$?  What is $\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\rfloor$ when $k=1$?  Are these the same?

Comment: ah, no it is not.

Comment: You could go and show that $\lfloor \frac{2k+1}{2}\rfloor = \lfloor \frac{2k}{2}\rfloor$ for all integers $k$, but that is a different problem.

Comment: The statement isnt generally true. For some _k_ is true, for some others values of _k_ isnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2} \right\rfloor =  \left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor
$$
In the case that $k=3$, 
$$
 \left\lfloor \frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor =  \left\lfloor 2  \right\rfloor \ne  \left\lfloor 1.5 \right\rfloor
$$